# JavaFX not working properly with Internet Exploer 9 and 10 ( if Document mode is set to IE9 )

Tags: javafx, internet-explorer-10

I faced a problem in depolying JavaFX app in web and I got issue only with IE10 or IE9 and to be more precisely  when the Document Mode is 9 , issue is that Browser cannot recognize the object 'app' which will be defined by JavaFx after being loaded . This object 'app' calls  function  'tellme' with parameters. What I expect to see log on browser console: "____a OK maher", but what I get is an error message:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'tellme'
```

Other info:

- after launching Java there is prompt about publisher, permissions, see Image#1

[image]

just accept and go on.

- Website requests access and control over JavaFx app ( there is JS <==> JavaFX ) and so there is a security warning about that and requests user to allow. see Image #2

[image]

Here I noted that in Document Mode IE9 I got this warning immediately after first one ..but on other browsers ( including DM IE8,DM IE7 ) its appearing after pressing clicl that means after calling JavaFx from JS via app.tellme

- Again Issue only with IE, with other browser its OK ( Chrome, Opera, FF,.. etc ) also no issue with  earlier versions of IE  7 and 8  ; briefly I have the problem only if IE document mode is set to IE9
- This has nothing with Signing .. I have a valid sign code cert ..and surely I set correct permissions on manifest ( codebase, permissions, ...etc) but really this has nothing with this issue .. only 2nd warning disappears but issue still persists.
- To simulate the issue:

  1-Open main.html (codes below) with IE9 or IE10, press F12 to set Document Mode to IE 9.

  2-press start, and accept to run that app, then accept the following prompt to allow accessing 
   JavaFx via JS.

  3-press clicl, on browser console you will see the error message .. what I expected to solve this issue to see output :"____a OK maher"

codes:

main.java ( JavaFX app) :**updated**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.im.oor;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

/**
 *
 * @author maher
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {



        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        publishServices();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    private static JSObject jsWin;

    private void publishServices() {

        try {


        JSObject jsWins = getHostServices().getWebContext();

        jsWins.setMember("app", new JavaAplicationCallBack());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("error with JSObject : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class JavaAplicationCallBack {

        public String tellme(String uu) {
            return "OK " + uu;

        }
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

main.html (webpage):**updated**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">-->
        <script src="web-files/dtjava.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="jfx.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a.ll").live("click", function(event) {
                    callit('hi ');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="launchit();" >start</a>
        <a class='ll' href="#"  >clicl</a>
        <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
        <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jfx.js ( javascript used on main.html ):**updated**

```
function javafxEmbed() {
    dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'TestIdleCallJavaFx.jnlp',
                //url: 'Testjfx.jnlp',
                placeholder: 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                jnlp_content: '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'
                //jnlp_content: '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'
            },
            {
                javafx: '2.2+'

            },
            {}
        );

        }






function launchit(){
dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
}


function callit(aa){
alert(aa);
console.log("____ "+aa);
var ttt=app.tellme("maher ");
console.log("____a "+ttt);

}
```

- Note that if you build code it may generate different jnlp_content that what I have. so just update it.

<strike>* I zipped all files into http://ulozto.cz/xV2vrQTd/javafx-dm-ie9-zip</strike>

*** Source code is here : http://247workers.com/JFX_src/TestIdleCallJavaFx.zip**

**Here some steps how to successfully get it work:**

**1- I am using latest version of JDK/JRE 7u45**

**2- using Menu File ==> import ==> import from zip**

**3- Clean And Build**

**4-copy all content under dist in project into directory work and overwrite any thing if you already have something there.**

**5- it will be better to show Java Console during deploying via Control Panel ==> Java ==> Advanced ==> under Java console, choose show console.**

- About using

< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">

to enforce using older rendering engine but this wont be accepted on our enterprise project Im working  on.

I hope I will get assistance here ... sorry for long post but I wanted to be very specific and provide all necessary info .

Comment: Does `getWebContext` returns a value != `null` and does `setMember` don't throw an JSException?

Comment: There is no thrown exception on console, so I expect that jsWins is not null .. I will check it and let you know …

Comment: well, I did update my main post, and I have checked jsWins and put in try block .. no exception had been thrown there .. another hint?

Comment: I've found a FAQ entry for this security warning. See http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javascript_applet.xml for  description. They say evaluate the [Caller-Allowable_Codebase Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html)

Comment: Actually I have signed app and inserted all necessary inputs to manifest and it working and so I don't get the 2nd notification as in Image 2 .. but this won't solve the problem .. I don't think its security issue…

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the Java plugin.  As far as I can tell there is no workaround and the bug is still present in Java 8.

For some reason in IE9 and IE10 (edge won't load Java at all for me) the `toString()` method is called on the object you want to expose to the browser.  This is evident by using the developer tools to inspect `app`.

I've turned on debug for the browser and plugin (`JPI_PLUGIN2_DEBUG=1` and `JPI_PLUGIN2_VERBOSE=1`) and I'm seeing some differences between IE8 and IE9 mode, but nothing showing me exactly where in the plugin code the object is being transformed to a `String`.

The next course of action is to try and override the plugin with a custom build to see where the problem is actually occurring.  However, that may be more trouble than it's worth since it's already been determined the bug is in the plugin and there's no known workaround.  In other words, even if a fix was found you probably couldn't deploy a patched version of Java to your enterprise customers.  It looks like the only solution is to use a different browser or IE in documentMode 8 or less.

I've included some logs for completeness.  Note: I changed the names of the jnlp and classes to mirror my environment, but the result is the same.

**IE9 Console Log**

```
NativeLibLoader: resolving loaded C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\jp2iexp.d
ll
   (Succeeded)
IExplorerPlugin.IExplorerPlugin(0x3aaefe8)
IExplorerPlugin.IExplorerPlugin(1.8.0)
NativeLibLoader: C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\bin\jp2native.dll doesn't exist
NativeLibLoader: trying to load C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\bin\jp2native.dll
  (Succeeded)
IExplorerPlugin.addParameters(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8)
IExplorerPlugin.CreateControlWindow(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8, hWndParent = 0x3071e
, hWndControlWindow = 0x1d0348)
IExplorerPlugin.SetObjectRects(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8, left = 8, right = 308, to
p = 26, bottom = 126, appletID = null, activated = false)
{IExplorerPlugin.InPlaceActivate(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8) entered
}IExplorerPlugin.InPlaceActivate(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8) exited
IExplorerPlugin.SetObjectRects(cAxControl = 0x3aaefe8, left = 8, right = 308, to
p = 26, bottom = 126, appletID = null, activated = true)
  Attempting to start applet
1 JavaFX runtime found.
  1) JavaFX 8.0.0 found at C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\
JVMLauncher.start: launcher params:
        <-Djnlp.fx=8.0.0>
        <-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\deploy.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java
\jre8\lib\javaws.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\plugin.jar>
        <-Djava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\classes>
        <--->
        <-->
        <sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain>
        <read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2136_pipe2,write_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2136_pipe3>
JVMLauncher.start(): now - user.startApplet(): 14520 us
JVMLauncher.processArg[0]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\jp2launcher.exe
JVMLauncher.processArg[1]: -D__jvm_launched=22791732422
JVMLauncher.processArg[2]: -D__applet_launched=22791717902
JVMLauncher.processArg[3]: -Djnlp.fx=8.0.0
JVMLauncher.processArg[4]: sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain
JVMLauncher.processArg[5]: read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2136_pipe2,write_pipe_name=jpi
2_pid2136_pipe3
JVMLauncher.processArgs total len: 234, custArgsMaxLen: 8044
JVMLauncher.afterStart(): starting JVM process watcher
JVMInstance.start: JVMID original params array:
        [0][0]: <-Djnlp.fx=8.0.0>
        [0][1]: <-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\deploy.jar;C:\PROGR
A~2\Java\jre8\lib\javaws.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\plugin.jar>
        [0][2]: <-Djava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\classes>
        [4][0]: <null>
JVMInstance for 1.8.0.ea sending start applet message
  isRelaunch: false
  appletLaunchTime: 22791717902
  Parameters:
    jnlp_href=Main.jnlp
    launchjnlp=
    code=dummy.class
    java_status_events=true
    type=application/x-java-applet
    separate_jvm=true
    javafx_version=2.2+
    javafx_applet_id=dtjava-app-1
    codebase=http://172.16.218.1/
    width=300
    name=dtjava-app-1
    id=dtjava-app-1
    scriptable=true
    height=100
JVMInstance.registerApplet for applet ID 1, plugin sun.plugin2.main.server.IExpl
orerPlugin@44dec8
  Received applet ID [AppletID 1]
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing GetProxyMessage
Delegate to plugin instance on browser main thread.
Browser main thread handle GetProxyMessage.
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing GetProxyMessage
Delegate to plugin instance on browser main thread.
Browser main thread handle GetProxyMessage.
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing CookieOpMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing CookieOpMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptGetWindowMessage
  LiveConnectSupport: retained [BrowserSideObject 0x3ecd730] for applet 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptGetWindowMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptEvalMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptMemberOpMessage
LiveConnectSupport.sendRemoteJavaObjectOp: CALL_METHOD "toString"
AbstractPlugin.doJavaObjectOp starting to wait for result ID 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaReplyMessage
JVMInstance received JavaReplyMessage with result ID 1
AbstractPlugin.doJavaObjectOp ending wait for result ID 1
LiveConnectSupport: result [ResultID 1] = JavaApplicationCallBack Test
JVMInstance for 1.8.0.ea sending release remote object message for ID 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptReleaseObjectMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptReleaseObjectMessage
  LiveConnectSupport: schedule release [BrowserSideObject 0x3ecd730] for applet
1
```

**IE8 Console Log**

```
NativeLibLoader: resolving loaded C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\jp2iexp.d
ll
   (Succeeded)
IExplorerPlugin.IExplorerPlugin(0x4c1efe8)
IExplorerPlugin.IExplorerPlugin(1.8.0)
NativeLibLoader: C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\bin\jp2native.dll doesn't exist
NativeLibLoader: trying to load C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\bin\jp2native.dll
  (Succeeded)
IExplorerPlugin.addParameters(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8)
IExplorerPlugin.CreateControlWindow(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8, hWndParent = 0xd04b4
, hWndControlWindow = 0x1a030a)
IExplorerPlugin.SetObjectRects(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8, left = -9990, right = -96
90, top = 28, bottom = 128, appletID = null, activated = false)
{IExplorerPlugin.InPlaceActivate(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8) entered
}IExplorerPlugin.InPlaceActivate(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8) exited
IExplorerPlugin.SetObjectRects(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8, left = -9990, right = -96
90, top = 28, bottom = 128, appletID = null, activated = true)
  Attempting to start applet
1 JavaFX runtime found.
  1) JavaFX 8.0.0 found at C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\
JVMLauncher.start: launcher params:
        <-Djnlp.fx=8.0.0>
        <-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\deploy.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java
\jre8\lib\javaws.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\plugin.jar>
        <-Djava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\classes>
        <--->
        <-->
        <sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain>
        <read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2740_pipe2,write_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2740_pipe3>
JVMLauncher.start(): now - user.startApplet(): 12763 us
JVMLauncher.processArg[0]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\jp2launcher.exe
JVMLauncher.processArg[1]: -D__jvm_launched=25562522742
JVMLauncher.processArg[2]: -D__applet_launched=25562509979
JVMLauncher.processArg[3]: -Djnlp.fx=8.0.0
JVMLauncher.processArg[4]: sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain
JVMLauncher.processArg[5]: read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2740_pipe2,write_pipe_name=jpi
2_pid2740_pipe3
JVMLauncher.processArgs total len: 234, custArgsMaxLen: 8044
JVMLauncher.afterStart(): starting JVM process watcher
JVMInstance.start: JVMID original params array:
        [0][0]: <-Djnlp.fx=8.0.0>
        [0][1]: <-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\deploy.jar;C:\PROGR
A~2\Java\jre8\lib\javaws.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\lib\plugin.jar>
        [0][2]: <-Djava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\classes>
        [4][0]: <null>
JVMInstance for 1.8.0.ea sending start applet message
  isRelaunch: false
  appletLaunchTime: 25562509979
  Parameters:
    jnlp_href=Main.jnlp
    launchjnlp=
    code=dummy.class
    java_status_events=true
    type=application/x-java-applet
    separate_jvm=true
    javafx_version=2.2+
    javafx_applet_id=dtjava-app-1
    codebase=http://172.16.218.1/
    width=300
    name=dtjava-app-1
    id=dtjava-app-1
    scriptable=true
    height=100
JVMInstance.registerApplet for applet ID 1, plugin sun.plugin2.main.server.IExpl
orerPlugin@66906f
  Received applet ID [AppletID 1]
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing GetProxyMessage
Delegate to plugin instance on browser main thread.
Browser main thread handle GetProxyMessage.
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing GetProxyMessage
Delegate to plugin instance on browser main thread.
Browser main thread handle GetProxyMessage.
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing CookieOpMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing CookieOpMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptGetWindowMessage
  LiveConnectSupport: retained [BrowserSideObject 0x397ca24] for applet 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing StartAppletAckMessage with:
        appletID: 1
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptGetWindowMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptEvalMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptMemberOpMessage
IExplorerPlugin.SetObjectRects(cAxControl = 0x4c1efe8, left = 10, right = 310, t
op = 28, bottom = 128, appletID = [AppletID 1], activated = true)
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptReleaseObjectMessage
JVMInstance (1.8.0.ea) processing JavaScriptReleaseObjectMessage
  LiveConnectSupport: schedule release [BrowserSideObject 0x397ca24] for applet
1
```

**Stacktrace of toString() being called in IE9**

```
at Main$JavaAplicationCallBack.toString(Main.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.doMemberOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.setMember(Unknown Source)
at Main.publishServices(Main.java:55)
at Main.start(Main.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```